# Uncaught TypeError: Vue.extend is not a function

Tags: vuejs3

I get the error below in the browser after having migrated from vue 2

`Uncaught TypeError: Vue.extend is not a function`

my main.js file is below

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import Clipboard from 'v-clipboard'
import Vidle from 'v-idle'

const app = createApp({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  axios,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).mount('#app')

app.use(store)
app.use(router)
app.use(Vidle)
app.use(Clipboard)
app.use(VueAxios, axios)

app.config.productionTip = false;

export const stores = store
```

These are my plugins and dependencies below, which one of these might me causing the error in the browser?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "v-clipboard": "^2.2.3",
    "v-idle": "^0.2.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.1",
    "vue-pdf-app": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  }
```

How do I fix this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't help but wonder, are you calling `Vue.extend(...)` anywhere in code not shown?

Comment: I am not  calling anything Vue.extend(...), I suspect it is one of my packages that is causing this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vue.extend` does not exist in Vue 3. One of your plugins must be using it, meaning that unless your plugin has an updated version it won't be compatible.

The error should contain a stack trace containing the path of the incompatible plugin. If not then remove all plugins and then add them back in one by one until the error occurs.

Comment: I have identified the package causing this to be `v-idle`